# How can I sum values at MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, search, view, sum

How can I sum values at MVC view?
I want to sum all **KwotaOplaty** records that are now displayed.
Notice that i'm using SEARCHING (at controller) so when i search specific records i want to sum them all.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string oplataTyp, string szukajRej)
        {
            var TypLista = new List<RodzajOplaty>();
            var TypWyszukaj = from d in db.Oplaty orderby d.RodzajOplaty select d.RodzajOplaty;
            TypLista.AddRange(TypWyszukaj.Distinct());
            ViewBag.oplataTyp = new SelectList(TypLista);


            var oplaty = from p in db.Oplaty select p;

            RodzajOplaty RodzajOplaty;

            if (Enum.TryParse<RodzajOplaty>(oplataTyp, out RodzajOplaty))
            {
                oplaty = oplaty.Where(x => x.RodzajOplaty == RodzajOplaty);
            }


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(szukajRej))
            {
                oplaty = oplaty.Where(s => s.TablicaRejstracyjna.Contains(szukajRej));
            }

            return View(oplaty.ToList());
        }
```

View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<AutoMonit.Models.Oplata>

    <h2>Zestawienie opłat pojazdów</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Utwórz", "Create")
    </p>

    @*@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>Numer rejestracyjny: </div>
        <div>@Html.TextBox("NumerRej")</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Szukaj" />
    }*@

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Oplatas", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Rodzaj oplaty: @Html.DropDownList("oplataTyp", "Wszystkie")<br />
           Numer rejestracyjny: @Html.TextBox("szukajRej") <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Szukaj" />
        </p>
    }

    <br />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TablicaRejstracyjna)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pojazd.Marka)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataOplaty)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrzebiegOplaty)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RodzajOplaty)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.KwotaOplaty)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DodatkoweInformacjeOplaty)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TablicaRejstracyjna)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pojazd.Marka)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataOplaty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrzebiegOplaty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RodzajOplaty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KwotaOplaty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DodatkoweInformacjeOplaty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edytuj", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Szczegóły", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Usuń", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>

    <hr />
    <h2>Suma kosztów:</h2>
@*Here i want to display sum*@
```

Comment: Sum them in the controller and pass the value to the view (as a property in your view model, or as a `ViewBag` property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to that using Sum method and putting the result value in a ViewBag value and referencing it using Razor. It should be something like this:

In the Controller

```
ViewBag.Total = yourCollection.Sum(x => x.ThePropertyYouWantToSum);
```

In the View

```
@ViewBag.Total
```

Remember to include

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Model.Sum(b => b.KwotaOplaty)
```

Comment: @Piter yeah you didnt really need the Display helper.. you can just output the sum

Comment: Thank you @JamieD77. I got stuck trying to do something like value++ . Your Answer pointed me in the right direction: @(Model.element + 1)